# Why is my API still requiring authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a RESTful API in Java using Spring Boot and began implementing JWT authentication by following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/#The-RESTful-Spring-Boot-API-Overview). After reading some advice on Hacker New, I decided not to use JWT and went and undid everything I added. However, when I re-ran my Java program, and made requests using Postman, it says I am unauthorized - which it did not prior to initially setting up JWT authorization.

My question is, is there a cache somewhere that I have to clear or am I just missing something? Why is it now requiring authorization?

Here is my project structure and code:

[image]

FlapiApplication.java

```
package com.package.flapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FlapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlapiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ListingRepository.java:

```
package com.package.flapi.repositories;

import com.dougmellon.flapi.models.Listing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ListingRepository extends JpaRepository<Listing, Long>{}
```

Listing.java

```
package com.package.flapi.models;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "listings")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Listing {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "unit_heading", nullable = false)
    private String unitHeading;

    @Column(name = "unit_type_id", nullable = false)
    private int unitTypeId;

    @Column(name = "number_of_bedrooms", nullable = false)
    private int numberOfBedrooms;

    @Column(name = "number_of_bathrooms", nullable = false)
    private double numberOfBathrooms;

    @Column(name = "number_of_balconies", nullable = false)
    private int numberOfBalconies;

    @Column(name = "leasing_info_id", nullable = false)
    private int leasingInfoId;

    @Column(name = "date_of_posting", nullable = false)
    private Date dateOfPosting;

    @Column(name = "date_available_from", nullable = false)
    private Date dateAvailableFrom;

    @Column(name = "posted_by", nullable = false)
    private int postedBy;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "unit_description", nullable = false)
    private String unitDescription;

    @Column(name = "carpet_area", nullable = false)
    private int carpetArea;

    @Column(name = "unit_number", nullable = false)
    private String unitNumber;

    @Column(name = "unit_floor_number", nullable = false)
    private int unitFloorNumber;

    @Column(name = "parent_unit_id", nullable = false)
    private int parentUnitId;

    public Listing() { }

    public Listing(String unitHeading, int unitTypeId, int numberOfBedrooms,
                   double numberOfBathrooms, int numberOfBalconies, int leasingInfoId,
                   Date dateOfPosting, Date dateAvailableFrom, int postedBy,
                   boolean isActive, String unitDescription, int carpetArea,
                   String unitNumber, int unitFloorNumber, int parentUnitId) {
        this.unitHeading = unitHeading;
        this.unitTypeId = unitTypeId;
        this.numberOfBedrooms = numberOfBedrooms;
        this.numberOfBathrooms = numberOfBathrooms;
        this.numberOfBalconies = numberOfBalconies;
        this.leasingInfoId = leasingInfoId;
        this.dateOfPosting = dateOfPosting;
        this.dateAvailableFrom = dateAvailableFrom;
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.unitDescription = unitDescription;
        this.carpetArea = carpetArea;
        this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
        this.unitFloorNumber = unitFloorNumber;
        this.parentUnitId = parentUnitId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUnitHeading() {
        return unitHeading;
    }

    public void setUnitHeading(String unitHeading) {
        this.unitHeading = unitHeading;
    }

    public int getUnitTypeId() {
        return unitTypeId;
    }

    public void setUnitTypeId(int unitTypeId) {
        this.unitTypeId = unitTypeId;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBedrooms() {
        return numberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBedrooms(int numberOfBedrooms) {
        this.numberOfBedrooms = numberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public double getNumberOfBathrooms() {
        return numberOfBathrooms;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBathrooms(double numberOfBathrooms) {
        this.numberOfBathrooms = numberOfBathrooms;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBalconies() {
        return numberOfBalconies;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBalconies(int numberOfBalconies) {
        this.numberOfBalconies = numberOfBalconies;
    }

    public int getLeasingInfoId() {
        return leasingInfoId;
    }

    public void setLeasingInfoId(int leasingInfoId) {
        this.leasingInfoId = leasingInfoId;
    }

    public Date getDateOfPosting() {
        return dateOfPosting;
    }

    public void setDateOfPosting(Date dateOfPosting) {
        this.dateOfPosting = dateOfPosting;
    }

    public Date getDateAvailableFrom() {
        return dateAvailableFrom;
    }

    public void setDateAvailableFrom(Date dateAvailableFrom) {
        this.dateAvailableFrom = dateAvailableFrom;
    }

    public int getPostedBy() {
        return postedBy;
    }

    public void setPostedBy(int postedBy) {
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public String getUnitDescription() {
        return unitDescription;
    }

    public void setUnitDescription(String unitDescription) {
        this.unitDescription = unitDescription;
    }

    public int getCarpetArea() {
        return carpetArea;
    }

    public void setCarpetArea(int carpetArea) {
        this.carpetArea = carpetArea;
    }

    public String getUnitNumber() {
        return unitNumber;
    }

    public void setUnitNumber(String unitNumber) {
        this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
    }

    public int getUnitFloorNumber() {
        return unitFloorNumber;
    }

    public void setUnitFloorNumber(int unitFloorNumber) {
        this.unitFloorNumber = unitFloorNumber;
    }

    public int getParentUnitId() {
        return parentUnitId;
    }

    public void setParentUnitId(int parentUnitId) {
        this.parentUnitId = parentUnitId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

ListingNotFoundException.java:

```
package com.package.flapi.exceptionhandlers;

public class ListingNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public ListingNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super("Could not find listing " + id);
    }
}
```

ListingController.java:

```
package com.package.flapi.controllers;

import com.dougmellon.flapi.assemblers.ListingModelAssembler;
import com.dougmellon.flapi.exceptionhandlers.ListingNotFoundException;
import com.dougmellon.flapi.models.Listing;
import com.dougmellon.flapi.repositories.ListingRepository;
import org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@RestController
public class ListingController {

    private final ListingRepository repository;
    private final ListingModelAssembler assembler;

    public ListingController(ListingRepository repository, ListingModelAssembler assembler) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

    // Aggregate root
    @GetMapping("/listings")
    public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Listing>> all() {
        List<EntityModel<Listing>> listings = repository.findAll().stream()
                .map(assembler::toModel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return CollectionModel.of(listings,
                linkTo(methodOn(ListingController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }

    @PostMapping("/listings")
    Listing newListing(@RequestBody Listing newListing) {
        return repository.save(newListing);
    }

    // Single listing
    @GetMapping("/listings/{id}")
    public EntityModel<Listing> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Listing listing = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ListingNotFoundException(id));

        return assembler.toModel(listing);
    }

    @PutMapping("/listings/{id}")
    Listing replaceListing(@RequestBody Listing newListing, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(listing -> {
                    listing.setUnitHeading(newListing.getUnitHeading());
                    listing.setUnitTypeId(newListing.getUnitTypeId());
                    listing.setNumberOfBedrooms(newListing.getNumberOfBedrooms());
                    listing.setNumberOfBathrooms(newListing.getNumberOfBathrooms());
                    listing.setNumberOfBalconies(newListing.getNumberOfBalconies());
                    listing.setLeasingInfoId(newListing.getLeasingInfoId());
                    listing.setDateOfPosting(newListing.getDateOfPosting());
                    listing.setDateAvailableFrom(newListing.getDateAvailableFrom());
                    listing.setPostedBy(newListing.getPostedBy());
                    listing.setActive(newListing.isActive());
                    listing.setUnitDescription(newListing.getUnitDescription());
                    listing.setCarpetArea(newListing.getCarpetArea());
                    listing.setUnitNumber(newListing.getUnitNumber());
                    listing.setUnitFloorNumber(newListing.getUnitFloorNumber());
                    listing.setParentUnitId(newListing.getParentUnitId());
                    return repository.save(listing);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newListing.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newListing);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/listings/{id}")
    void deleteListing(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

ListingNotFoundAdvice.java:

```
package com.package.flapi.controlleradvice;

import com.dougmellon.flapi.exceptionhandlers.ListingNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ListingNotFoundAdvice {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(ListingNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    String listingNotFoundHandler(ListingNotFoundException exception) {
        return exception.getMessage();
    }
}
```

ListingModelAssembler.java:

```
package com.package.flapi.assemblers;

import com.dougmellon.flapi.controllers.ListingController;
import com.dougmellon.flapi.models.Listing;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.RepresentationModelAssembler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@Component
public class ListingModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Listing, EntityModel<Listing>> {
    @Override
    public EntityModel<Listing> toModel(Listing listing) {
        return EntityModel.of(listing,
                linkTo(methodOn(ListingController.class).one(listing.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                linkTo(methodOn(ListingController.class).all()).withRel("listings"));
    }
}
```

I don't see any other references in my code that are still involving Spring Security or incorporating JWT's so I am not sure what is happening.

I am using PostgreSQL if that makes a difference.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dougmellon</groupId>
    <artifactId>flapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flapi</name>
    <description>FidoLease API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
# Database Properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

# Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Can you share `applicaton.properties` file as well?

Comment: I suspect you still have a reference to Spring Security in your pom.xml. Remove it.

Comment: @JohnSmith added.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I don't see anything I forgot to remove. I added the pom file to the post as well.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project, and make sure you refreshed the dependencies. Totally unrelated but which theme/icons are you using for Intellij?

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, I will give that a shot! I am using the One Dark (Vivid italic) theme and Atom Material Icons.

Comment: @M.Deinum that worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by @M.Deinum, to try a clean install and rebuild the project worked perfectly.